# Fazer o OpenSSL funcionar no PHP

Tags: php, openssl

Estou tentando fazer a extensão openssl funcionar no php, mas não consigo.

Estou usando o servidor interno do php 7.3.5 e Windows 10.

Eis o que já tentei:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "\\openssl.cnf";
putenv("OPENSSL_CONF=" . $dir);
$res = openssl_pkey_new(["config" => $dir]);
while($erro = openssl_error_string()){
  echo $erro . "<br>";
}
```

Retorno:

```
error:02001003:systemlibrary:fopen:No such process
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```